# Unable to find the shortest distance in graph using adjacent matrix in c

Tags: c, graph, dijkstra

I am trying to find the shortest distance between two nodes using adjacent matrix and recursive call, but for some reason it always returns 0, i cant find where things are going wrong.
The function 'shortestDist' is a recursive function which returns the shortest cost. If src node contains a direct path to destination than the cost is directly added to array. but if it doesnt the possible nodes replace the source node and a recursive function is called. for a node to replace a source node it must meet the following requirements : 1- it shouldn't be visited, 2- the distance between this.node and destination should be less than prevsrc and dst, 3- the node should not be the destination itself.

`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define X 99
int **graph;
int numNodes;
char nodes[10][10];
void createGraph(int);
void printGraph();
void addPath(char[],char[],int);
void deleteGraph();
int shortestDist(int,int);
int visited[10];
int min(int[]);
void main()
{
   int i,j;
    createGraph(5);
    addPath("a","b",3);
    addPath("b","c",5);
    addPath("a","c",9);
    printf ("\n%d\n",shortestDist(0,2));
    printGraph();
}
void createGraph(int no){
   int i,j;
   numNodes=no;
    graph = malloc(sizeof(int*)*no);
    for(i=0;i<no;i++){
        graph[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*no);
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<no;i++){
       printf("Enter %d node: ",i+1);
       scanf("%s",&nodes[i]);
        for(j=0;j<no;j++){
            graph[i][j] = X;
        }
    }
}
void addPath(char from[],char to[],int dist){
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++){
      for(j=0;j<numNodes;j++){
         if(strcmp(from,nodes[i])==0 && strcmp(to,nodes[j])==0){
            graph[i][j]=dist; 
         }
      }
   }
}
void printGraph(){
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++){
        for(j=0;j<numNodes;j++){
            printf("%d ",graph[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++){
       printf("%d ",visited[i]);
   }
}
void deleteGraph(){
   free(graph);
}
int shortestDist(int src,int dst){
   int possPaths=0,i;
   int count=0;
   visited[src] = 1;
   for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++){
      if(graph[src][i]!=X){
         possPaths++;
      }
   }
    int possNodes[possPaths];
   for(i=0;i<possPaths;i++){
      possNodes[i] = X;
   }
   if(graph[src][dst]!=X){
      possNodes[count] = graph[src][dst];
      count++;
   }
   for(i=0;i<numNodes;i++){
      if(graph[src][i]!=X && visited[i]==0 && i!=dst){
         printf("?");
         possNodes[count] = graph[src][i] + shortestDist(i,dst);
         count++;
      }
   }
   for(i=0;i<possPaths;i++){
      printf("->%d\n",possNodes[i]);
   }
   return min(possNodes);
}
int min(int arr[]){
    int minimum=arr[0],i;
    for(i=0 ; i<numNodes ; i++){
       if(arr[i]<minimum){
          minimum = arr[i];
      }
   }
    return minimum;
}
```

`

Output is always returing 0.

Comment: You should also provide sample input.

Comment: _Output is always returing 0_ is not true; if I enter `a b c d e`, I get 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `min` function processes `numNodes` array elements, but it is passed the array `possNodes` with only `possPaths` elements, hence it fails to return a correct `minimum`.
I suggest to change it to

```
int min(int possPaths, int arr[possPaths])
{
    int minimum = X;
    for (int i = 0; i < possPaths; ++i)
        if (arr[i] < minimum) minimum = arr[i];
    return minimum;
}
```

and invoke it so:

```
    return min(possPaths, possNodes);
```